# distribution of books among students

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

There are $p$ students and $q$ books where $q>p$ and all books are different, but each student will get a minimum of $1$ book and a maximum of $(p – 1)$ books. Find the total number of ways of distributing the books?

#### My thought was

Total - invalid cases
total $=p^q$

invalid

- case 1 -when all to one student - $p$ ways
- case 2- when all books are divided between $2$ students $(2<p)$, $q^2$ ways
- case 3- when all books are divided between $3$ students $(3<p)$, $q^3$ ways
  and so on up to when all are divided between $ p-1$ students.

Above cases are for satisfying the criteria of min 1 book to each student.

Now for maximum $p-1$ books (when each student have at least one) I am having confusion as to the assumptions to take and all.

Comment: Have fun doing that. This is phrased like a homework question. You should include your own thoughts on the question.

Comment: Each of the books is different from the other @drhab already mentioned in question.

Comment: My thought was -
Total-invalid cases
total-p^q
invalid-
case 1 -when all to one student-p ways
case 2- when all books are divided between 2 students(2<p)-q^2 ways
case 3- when all books are divided between 3 students(3<p)-q^3 ways
and so on upto when all are divided between p-1 students.
Above cases are for satisfying the criteria of min 1 book to each student.
Now for maximum p-1 books(when each student have atleast one) i am having confusion as to the assumptions to take and all.

Answer (score 0):

This is a direct application of the [stars-and-bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) technique.

Comment: That technique is used for alike/indistinguishable objects.In this case all the books are different.